# How to make 3d cylinder/cube on ArUco marker?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I'm working on a small project in which I have to detect aruco marker from the image then make 3d cylinder or cube covering all white boxes.

In below code their is a detect_marker() function in which I have to return Aruco_list which I don't know how to do. If there is any tutorial from were I can learn this you can suggest me.

```py
    def getCameraMatrix():
        with np.load('System.npz') as X:
            camera_matrix, dist_coeff, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs')]
        return camera_matrix, dist_coeff

    """
    Function Name : sin()
    Input: angle (in degrees)
    Output: value of sine of angle specified
    Purpose: Returns the sine of angle specified in degrees
    """
    def sin(angle):
        return math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    """
    Function Name : cos()
    Input: angle (in degrees)
    Output: value of cosine of angle specified
    Purpose: Returns the cosine of angle specified in degrees
    """
    def cos(angle):
        return math.cos(math.radians(angle))



    ################################################################################


    """
    Function Name : detect_markers()
    Input: img (numpy array), camera_matrix, dist_coeff
    Output: aruco list in the form [(aruco_id_1, centre_1, rvec_1, tvec_1),(aruco_id_2,
            centre_2, rvec_2, tvec_2), ()....]
    Purpose: This function takes the image in form of a numpy array, camera_matrix and
             distortion matrix as input and detects ArUco markers in the image. For each
             ArUco marker detected in image, paramters such as ID, centre coord, rvec
             and tvec are calculated and stored in a list in a prescribed format. The list
             is returned as output for the function
    """
    def detect_markers(img, camera_matrix, dist_coeff):
        markerLength = 100
        aruco_list = []
        ######################## INSERT CODE HERE ########################


        ##################################################################
        return aruco_list

    """
    Function Name : drawAxis()
    Input: img (numpy array), aruco_list, aruco_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff
    Output: img (numpy array)
    Purpose: This function takes the above specified outputs and draws 3 mutually
             perpendicular axes on the specified aruco marker in the image and
             returns the modified image.
    """
    def drawAxis(img, aruco_list, aruco_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff):
        for x in aruco_list:
            if aruco_id == x[0]:
                rvec, tvec = x[2], x[3]
        markerLength = 100
        m = markerLength/2
        pts = np.float32([[-m,m,0],[m,m,0],[-m,-m,0],[-m,m,m]])
        pt_dict = {}
        imgpts, _ = cv2.projectPoints(pts, rvec, tvec, camera_matrix, dist_coeff)
        for i in range(len(pts)):
             pt_dict[tuple(pts[i])] = tuple(imgpts[i].ravel())
        src = pt_dict[tuple(pts[0])];   dst1 = pt_dict[tuple(pts[1])];
        dst2 = pt_dict[tuple(pts[2])];  dst3 = pt_dict[tuple(pts[3])];

        img = cv2.line(img, src, dst1, (0,255,0), 4)
        img = cv2.line(img, src, dst2, (255,0,0), 4)
        img = cv2.line(img, src, dst3, (0,0,255), 4)
        return img

    """
    Function Name : drawCube()
    Input: img (numpy array), aruco_list, aruco_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff
    Output: img (numpy array)
    Purpose: This function takes the above specified outputs and draws a cube
             on the specified aruco marker in the image and returns the modified
             image.
    """
    def drawCube(img, ar_list, ar_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff):
        for x in ar_list:
            if ar_id == x[0]:
                rvec, tvec = x[2], x[3]
        markerLength = 100
        m = markerLength/2
        ######################## INSERT CODE HERE ########################


        ##################################################################
        return img

    """
    Function Name : drawCylinder()
    Input: img (numpy array), aruco_list, aruco_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff
    Output: img (numpy array)
    Purpose: This function takes the above specified outputs and draws a cylinder
             on the specified aruco marker in the image and returns the modified
             image.
    """
    def drawCylinder(img, ar_list, ar_id, camera_matrix, dist_coeff):
        for x in ar_list:
            if ar_id == x[0]:
                rvec, tvec = x[2], x[3]
        markerLength = 100
        radius = markerLength/2; height = markerLength*1.5
        ######################## INSERT CODE HERE ########################


        ##################################################################
        return img

    """
    MAIN CODE
    This main code reads images from the test cases folder and converts them into
    numpy array format using cv2.imread. Then it draws axis, cubes or cylinders on
    the ArUco markers detected in the images.
    """


    if __name__=="__main__":
        cam, dist = getCameraMatrix()
        img = cv2.imread("..\\TestCases\\image_1.jpg")
        aruco_list = detect_markers(img, cam, dist)
        for i in aruco_list:
            img = drawAxis(img, aruco_list, i[0], cam, dist)
            ##  img = drawCube(img, aruco_list, i[0], cam, dist)
            ##  img = drawCylinder(img, aruco_list, i[0], cam, dist)
        cv2.imshow("img", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm very new to these stuffs so it's seems to a bit difficult for me. Please help me out.

Below is the ArUco code on which I have to perform the above task 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

to detect the aruco marker you need the image or frame, the aruco dictionary that you are using for to create the markers in your case it should be or the aruco original or the 5x5 more info here: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d0b/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1Dictionary.html

then you can use this function to detect the aruco marker:

```
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.YOUR ARUCO DICTIONARY HERE)
parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()

corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(img, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
```

the ids is the list of the arucos detected and the corners is there positions.